# Reading a File to an Array

Tags: java, arrays

Alright, I am desperately in need of help here. I am taking a beginning programming class in college and am almost done with the semester and have understood most stuff without 2 much difficulty but in this case everything has gone way over my head.

My professor has asked us to create a program that reads a text file containing 2 fields to an array. The first field contains the numbers 1-7 which represent days of the week and the second field contains temperature for those days.

Once the program reads the file into the array, you must find the avg temperature for each day of the week( Example being 5 mondays all with different temps what is the avg?) Then it needs to calculate high temp and low temp.

After this is done the program needs to write the information into a new file

```
Day__High__Low __Avg
1
2
3
4
```

Now I have been working on this for 2 weeks now and the professor already extended the deadline for a week and my program is due tomorrow so I need help.

What I need is a simple way to read a txt file into an array then I will do the logic myself, and then a simple way to write the array into another file. I have tried a dozen things watched several videos and I just cant get anything to work.

Once I can get something to read and to write to a file I feel confident that I can figure out the logic to do the work.

Please Help

Tried somethign similar

```
try {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("inputfile.dat"));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: [How to read a file in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/). Get started! :)

Comment: What have you done so far? I suggest you look at this [article](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml) and this [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).

Comment: Sorry but we don't do assignments here, but we'll help in solving particular problems you have on an assignment. But we need to see a valid effort. So if you have tried something, show us your code. This problem seems to be easily solved. So the quicker you show us what you've tried, the sooner you'll be able to complete the assignment.

Comment: I dont want anyone to do my Asignment for me, I want to know how to read a txt file to an array. Nothing has helped I have spent 20-30 hours on this and gotten no where and keep deleting and starting over. And linking me to another tutorial that ive already tried to make work and not gotten anything to happen just makes things more miserable. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

Comment: Also tried this series http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L06uGnF4IpY&list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28 couldnt make it work

Comment: watched these as well, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0DfmD0KKyc&list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28 I cant even duplicate what I see keep getting red text and compiling errors

Answer (score 0):

IO skeleton for pretty much any read-text-then-output-text program:

```
Scanner data = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(<file>));
while (data.hasNextLine()) {
    String dataPoint = data.nextLine();
    ...
}
...
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(<file>);
for (...) {
    output.println(...);
}
output.close();
```

You'll need to add appropriate try-catch blocks for IO exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create the code using Scanner and PrintWriter :

```
import java.awt.PageAttributes;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CalcAvgTemp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File inFile = new File("E:\\inputFile.txt");
        File outFile = new File("E:\\outputFile.txt");
        int[] day = new int[7];
        int[] count = new int[7];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(inFile);
        sc.nextLine();  // move to second line assuming file is not empty.
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = sc.nextLine().trim();
            String[] splitStr = s.split(" ");
            day[Integer.parseInt(splitStr[0])-1] += Integer.parseInt(splitStr[1]);
            count[Integer.parseInt(splitStr[0])-1]++;
        }

        PrintWriter outFileWriter = new PrintWriter(outFile);
        outFileWriter.println("Day__High__Low __Avg");
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
            int j=i+1;
            double d = (double)day[i]/count[i];
            outFileWriter.println(j + " " + d);
        }
        outFileWriter.close();
    }
}
```

I used input file as :

```
    day temp

    1 20
    2 30
    3 40
    4 20
    5 60
    6 30
    7 10
    1 34
    2 34
    3 32
    4 34
    5 45
    6 34
    7 23
    1 12
    2 10
    3 20
    4 23
    5 67
    6 23
    7 12
    1 26
```

I go output as :

```
Day__High__Low __Avg
1 23.0
2 24.666666666666668
3 30.666666666666668
4 25.666666666666668
5 57.333333333333336
6 29.0
7 15.0
```

Comment: Thank you, It works and even better its something I can take apart duplicate and figure out how to do it myself. Your a godsend m8 would upvote you if I were allowed. Now to figure out how to write my own and incorporate my own logi o7